# Could not find or load main class package.class

Tags: java, command-line

I know this question has already been answered many times, but unfortunately I couldn't find the right answer to my questions.

below is my package structure and inside my package I have SimpleTest.java

d:\junit\src\junitfaq\SimpleTest.java

inside d:\junit\src> i tried to compile SimpleTest.java and it successfully compiled using the command below.

d:\junit\src>javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java

but when i try to run the program using command line below

d:\junit\src>java junitfaq.SimpleTest

this error occured. Error: Could not find or load main class junitfaq.SimpleTest

I tried running it by accessing junitfaq package by using this command

d:\junit\src\junitfaq>java -cp . SimpleTest

the program run perfectly. A little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Find your `SampleTest.class` file (unless you already built a JAR) and determine the correct path.

Comment: I haven't yet built a JAR and SimpleTest.class is located in the same package together with SimpleTest.java. that's why when i tried to run it with this command "java -cp . SimlpeTest" it work fine but when I try to run it with this command "java junitfaq.SimpleTest" could not find or load main class occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you declared your SimpleTest class to be a member of the junitfaq package? If you have, you should be able to run it from the src directory like `java junitfaq.SimpleTest` but you should get an error like this if you try to run it from within the junitfaq directory: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SimpleTest (wrong name: junitfaq/SimpleTest)`

Make sure your SimpleTest class starts with `package junitfaq;`

Edit: Here's a working example incorporating the comments below.

> login@domain:~/temp> mkdir src
>   login@domain:~/temp> cd src
>   login@domain:~/temp/src> mkdir junitfaq
>   login@domain:~/temp/src> nano junitfaq/SimpleTest.java

The contents of SimpleTest.java are as follows when I exit nano:

```
package junitfaq;

public class SimpleTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Test");
        }
}
```

> login@domain:~/temp/src> javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java
>   login@domain:~/temp/src> java junitfaq.SimpleTest
>   Test

Comment: I tried to compile it using this command->                                d:\junit\src>javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java and it compiled successfully. But shouldn't be after i compile the SimpleTest.class it will be stored inside the package junitfaq? how come after I compile it is still in the same folder together with the SimpleTest.java and the junitfaq package is still empty.

Comment: It will compile successfully either way. The difference is in how you run it. If you do not declare a package, you will need to run it using a classpath in which the class is at the root level (like at the current directory). However, if you declare a package at the top, then you will need to run the class from a level that mirrors your package structure. Keep in mind that packages do not create directories and vice versa - you must make them match each other.

Comment: To further comment, if your class is Test and you want it to be in a package called "test", you need to declare ```package test;``` at the top of Test.java and then make sure that Test.java resides in a directory called "test". After you compile it, you can change into the directory containing the "test" directory and run ```java test.Test```.

Comment: Yes I agree with your statement and that's what suppose to happen after i compile class Test. I declare package test at the top of Test.java, unfortunately after I compile, no such package called test is created. what's that suppose to mean?

Comment: In addition I tried compiling it in JCreator, package called "test" is created the only problem is when i compile it using command line i couldn't create a package called "test"

Comment: Try following the steps in my edited answer. I am still confused by your referring to packages being created for you, but perhaps the steps will clear it up. Packages are not created for you when you compile; you may be confusing them with jar libraries. Packages are just scoping tools that work when they mirror the logical directories the files are placed in.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now it's clear to me if what was the missing piece after i followed the steps in your edited answer. I forgot to add classpath in my directory which would produce "could not find or load main class". It took me 2 days to solved this problem of not figuring out if what was the root caused. If only I could give you +10 for your effort in helping me. thanks again.=)

Comment: This would be my first step in creating project in maven since i'm using JCreator. Unlike Neatbeans or Eclipse and other IDE's that are already supported by maven.

Comment: Glad you got things figured out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a classpath problem; you should double-check the location of your class file, the directory/package structure, the location from which you're trying to run the java command, and any classpath specified during execution.

For example, the following works for me:

```
$ mkdir junitfaq
$ cat >junitfaq/SimpleTest.java
package junitfaq;
public class SimpleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
^D
$ javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java
$ java junitfaq.SimpleTest
Hello, world!
$ java -cp . junitfaq.SimpleTest
Hello, world!
$
```

Not to belabor the obvious, but I noticed a spelling typo in one of your comments - you should also double-check that you're running the command as intended.

Comment: Shoudn't be after i compile using this command ->                     javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java the SimpleTest.class will be stored inside junitfaq package? because in my case after I compiled using this command ->                                                      javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java the SimpleTest.class is still in the same folder together with the SimpleTest.java and the junitfaq package is still empty.

Comment: Not sure I follow you - if you're compiling with `javac junitfaq/SimpleTest.java`, that implies that there is a directory called `junitfaq` with a file called `SimpleTest.java` in it.  After compiling, directory `junitfaq` will have both SimpleTest.java and SimpleTest.class files in it.  At that point, your filesystem structure *represents* the package structure - i.e., class file `SimpleTest.class` in directory `junitfaq` corresponds to `junitfaq.SimpleTest` from a java classpath perspective.

Answer (score 0):

trialYou could try putting your java and class files together with your libaray folder (if any) in a new file called "trial" in your C:\ directory then compile existing java file using the following->

C:\trial> javac -cp .;library folder* SimpleTest.java

(then)

C:\trial> java -cp .;library folder* SimpleTest

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: I tried to follow you instructions in the command line I use this ff. command->                                                                  c:\trial> javac -cp . junitfaq* SimpleTest.java                        this error occured: javac: file not found: SimpleTest.java.                 am i using the right command?